# netstat not showing any process running on any port in WSL Ubuntu in Windows 10

Tags: networking, server, nodejs

I have set up a nodejs server on 8080 port. When I put this command in the WSL Ubuntu terminal, it shows no results:

```
netstat -a | grep :8080
```

However, when I check this using Windows PowerShell command to see if this port is listening, it works:

[image]

**Is it normal or there is something wrong?**

**PS**: I need to know this because I can't access my server from any different network using the public IP even when port forwarding is done. I can access it only using my private IP and on same network/LAN.

So I am thinking maybe because the WSL doesn't show it as running, maybe that could be the reason.

Comment: I has the same situation when setting port forwarding for the local development. netsh’ing to the WSL Ubuntu eth0 IP solved the problem for the time being. Maybe it will help you somehow — netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8080 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=8080 connectaddress=192.168.178.93. Where the 192.168.178.93 is the WSL Ubuntu IP (‘ip a show eth0’).

Comment: @PabloBianchi just tried. It says Cannot open netlink socket: Protocol not supported

Comment: I've got this issue with another service, too. In short, netstat works perfect, as seen in `strace netstat`, but `/proc/net/tcp` and `/proc/net/udp` are not filled in WSL. I coludn't find any hint this will be changed, soon. But in the end I've used `telnet [host] [port]` to verify the open net path.

Answer (score 1):

WSL [doesn't seem to have good support](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2249) for commands like `ss` or `netstat`. The [solution provided](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2249#issuecomment-526133923) is to run the related Windows binary instead.

But the reason why you don't see the port listed is because `netstat` try to be friendly by changing the port number to a name (in this case `8080` to `http-alt`). Try instead:

```
netstat -a --numeric-ports | grep :8080
```

On a *real* Linux setup I would instead use `ss -plt src :8080`, to show all TCP sockets listening on the local 8080 port, alongside with processes connected. `ss` is included in iproute2 package and is the substitute of `netstat`.

To avoid the hassle of forwarding ports you could also try [tunneling alternatives](https://github.com/anderspitman/awesome-tunneling#open-source-at-least-with-a-reasonably-permissive-license). A popular open source one is [frp](https://github.com/fatedier/frp). With cloudlfare tunnel would be `cloudflared tunnel --url http://localhost:8080`.